# How do I use --add-opens together with IcedTea javaws?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, icedtea, icedtea-web

I tried something like that :

```
javaws -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal=ALL-UNNAMED my_jnlp_file.jnlp
```

And also tried in the jnlp :

```
<j2se java-vm-args="--add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms500m -Xmx4096m" />
```

I'm getting this error in the cmd console :

```
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
haring)
Error: --add-opens requires modules to be specified
Please press any key to close this window/get back prompt
```

Also tried providing these options with environment variables `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVAWS_J_OPTIONS` but no luck:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

I found a file `icedtea-web-image\bin\itw-modularjdk.args` inside the distribution of icedtea that has `--add-xxx` options so I've put the options there and it worked.

```
# -------------------------------------
# IcedTea-Web jigsaw run args (jdk9+)
# -------------------------------------

--add-reads=java.base=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-reads=java.desktop=ALL-UNNAMED,java.naming
--add-reads=java.naming=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop

--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.desktop/javax.jnlp=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop

--add-exports=java.base/com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.provider=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.validator=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.util.jar=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop

--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.applet=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.applet=ALL-UNNAMED,jdk.jsobject

--add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url=ALL-UNNAMED,java.desktop
```

However, I'm not quite sure this is the right place for this. I'd rather have it configured outside the distribution.

Could you please indicate the right way of passing these options ?